Failed to load pdf document using jspdf
I've been working on a function in JavaScript that allows me to download the content of a specified  as a PDF file. The function works by generating HTML content with print styles, converting it into a blob object, and then triggering a download using an anchor element.But when I try to open the pdf it showing like this:
Downloaded pdf
Here's the function:
downloadDivById(divId: string, fileName: string) {
    const printContent = document.getElementById(divId);
    if (!printContent) {
      console.error(`Div with ID '${divId}' not found.`);
      return;
    }

    // Generate HTML content with print styles
    const printHTML = `
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>${fileName}</title>
                <style>
                    /* Add @media print styles here */
                    @media print {
                        /* Additional CSS for printing */
                        body {
                            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; /* Safari and Chrome */
                            color-adjust: exact; /* Firefox */
                        }

                        /* Apply page break inside avoid to the main container and its child elements */
                        #${divId}, #${divId} div {
                            page-break-inside: avoid;
                            margin: 0; /* Remove margins */
                            padding: 0; /* Remove padding */
                        }

                        /* Add other print styles as needed */
                        ${this.getAllStyles()} /* Include all CSS rules from stylesheets */
                        ${this.getMediaQueryStyles()}
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                ${printContent.outerHTML}
            </body>
        </html>
    `;

    // Create a new blob object containing the HTML content
    const blob = new Blob([printHTML], { type: "application/pdf" });

    // Create a URL for the blob object
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Create an anchor element to trigger the download
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName + ".pdf";

    // Append the anchor element to the document body and trigger the click event
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();

    // Clean up by revoking the URL and removing the anchor element
    setTimeout(() => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 100);
}


I applied media queries for custom page breaks and css and I want to download a pdf with these css applied.
